# waterfalls graph for two data frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, waterfall

I have two data frames which have totally the same rows and columns.
df1 shows the percentage % of Mode :

```
                    pt      car     bike    walk
Equilibrium         28.80   36.82   3.55    30.83
No information      28.80   36.82   3.55    30.83
start               28.82   36.83   3.55    30.80
Equilibrium2        28.51   36.95   3.56    30.98
```

and df2 is Travel Time(minutes)

```
                    pt          car         bike    walk
Equilibrium         384651.50   216673.23   24136.57    88602.10
No information      397068.27   216640.15   24133.03    88565.93
start               386008.27   216664.17   24136.57    88521.93
Equilibrium2        383788.73   215751.85   26638.87    89602.90
```

I want to have such a following diagram that x-axis shows the percentage of Mode (df1) and the Y-axis shows the Travel Time (df2) for each column name such as:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try plotting the bars with bottoms:

```
colors = [f'C{i}' for i in range(4)]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(8,8))

for idx, ax in zip(df1.index, axes.ravel()):
    s1, s2 = df1.loc[idx].cumsum(),df2.loc[idx].cumsum()
    ax.bar(s1.shift(fill_value=0),df2.loc[idx],width=df1.loc[idx],
            bottom=s2.shift(fill_value=0), align='edge', color=colors)
    ax.set_title(idx)        

fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you also add the value of each axis inside of the box

Comment: See update for the color. Some of the boxes are too small to put any text inside.

Comment: I saw, nice, what about the horizontal and vertical lines? that helps to understand the exact amount

Comment: File "<ipython-input-94-f522f7460ab1>", line 1
    colors = [f'C{i}' for i in range(4)]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It's a valid python 3 syntax. I guess you are using Python 2. Please define the colors to your preference.

Comment: and what about the lines?horizontalalignment

Comment: There are no lines in your sketch, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I meant that when I look at the picture, I would like to know the exact amount for x-axis and y-axis, maybe can you show the values (for each box)?